# Screen overlay detected issue due to my app

Tags: android

There is screen overlay detected dialog (in android 6.0 but works fine in Android 10.0) when another app asks for system permissions, due to my app. As in my app I have used WindowManager to add a view like:

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O ?
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY :
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE |
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);


WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
windowManager.addView(new TextView(this), params);
```

The targetSdkVersion is 28

Comment: You can't really do anything about it, just an overlook on android teams part. On newer android versions all overlays are automatically hidden when permission dialog shows up.

Comment: @Pawel I have checked this app (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=info.kfsoft.android.TrafficIndicator), and  there is no such dialog (screen overlay detected dialog)